# How to change the type of _id in NEventStore.Persistence.MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, neventstore

By default, NEventStore.Persistence.MongoDB are using Int64 as _id's default type, but Int64 has a maxmium value, what if _id exceed that maxmium value? (I know it's hard to reach, but it will).

Can I change _id to Guid by using NEventStore?

Comment: Remember that GUIDs have a maximum value too. ;)

Comment: Int64 has a maximum value of 2^63-1 (signed). If all you saved was the `_id` alone, that'd be 8 bytes * 2^63 or 73 exabytes or 73,000 1TB harddisks... I'd be concerned about systems that use int64 because it's either a bottleneck (the counter), or uses HiLo and thus has non-monotonic keys, which should be a greater concern...